# PHP - How can I decode HTML special character strings to the actual characters?

Tags: php, utf-8, decode

I have some text, for example: `&ldquo; &pound; &nbsp; &euro; &ldquo;` I would like to decode it, so it outputs: `£ €`

I tried this code, but it doesn't work:

```
utf8_decode($utf8);
iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1', $utf8);
mb_convert_encoding($utf8, 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8');

utf8_encode($iso88591);
iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8', $iso88591);
mb_convert_encoding($iso88591, 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1');
```

I don't want to do a `str_replace` for each character.

Comment: That's HTML encoding, not UTF8.

Comment: html_entity_decode, they are entities, not a special encoding. https://3v4l.org/aIigr and/or http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: `&pound;` will output `£`, well unless it *not* my wallet.

Comment: Although the characters you want are not actually the entities you have. `&ldquo;` is a left double quote, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo html_entity_decode('&ldquo; &pound; &nbsp; &euro; &ldquo;');
```